# c# iTextSharp Object not set to instance

Tags: c#, visual-studio, itext

So I am trying to learn how to use iTextSharp with c# and winform to create a pdf based off input by a user of a program I created. I found this example code on the internet and it throws a couple different errors.

1.) Document has no pages, when I run the actual application

2.) Object Reference not set to an instance of an object. Point to the line with PdfWrtiter writer = Pdfwrite.GetInstance(document, output);

Basically, I'm trying to print on top of a pdf template, or image so that it looks like a sales form with description of the part.

```
 public void createPDF()
        {
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfReader reader = null;           
            MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();


            try
            {
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
                document.Open();

                // Load the background image and add it to the document structure
                reader = new PdfReader(Resources.GetSalesForm());
                PdfTemplate background = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);

                // Create a page in the document and add it to the bottom layer
                document.NewPage();
                _pcb = writer.DirectContentUnder;
                _pcb.AddTemplate(background, 0, 0);

                // Get the top layer and write some text
                _pcb = writer.DirectContent;
                _pcb.BeginText();

                if (_showRulers)
                {
                    PrintXAxis(800);
                    PrintXAxis(100);
                    PrintYAxis(40);
                    PrintYAxis(500);
                }
                SetFont36();
                PrintTextCentered("words", 280, 680);
                PrintTextCentered("words", 280, 190);

                SetFont18();
                PrintTextCentered("words", 280, 640);
                PrintTextCentered("words", 280, 160);

                _pcb.EndText();

                writer.Flush();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    reader.Close();
                }
                document.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Document has no pages: you close the document, but you didn't add any content. As you didn't add any content, no pages were created. It doesn't make sense to have a document without pages, hence the exception.
2. The second error can't occur where you say it occurs, but I see a lot of things that hurt the eyes in the rest of your code, so please throw everything you have so far and start anew.

When you start anew, why not use iText 7 for C#. Currently you are using an old version of iText. There is a jump-start tutorial on how to use the new version on the official iText web site: [iText 7L jump-start tutorial](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net-version). Check out [chapter 5](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/chapter-5-manipulating-existing-pdf-document)!

If you insist on using an old iText version, then be aware that you're doing it wrong. Adding content to an existing PDF is done with `PdfStamper`, not with `PdfWriter`. Adding text with `BeginText()`/`EndText()` is something you should only do when you know ISO-32000-1 by heart. Do you know that PDF reference by heart? No, then don't use `BeginText()`/`EndText()`, but use a convenience method such as `ColumnText.ShowTextAligned()` or use `ColumnText`, set the column dimensions, add elements to the column, and invoke `Go()` to render the content.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, I appreciate the feedback. As I stated above, this isn't my code it was a sample code I found online for what Im trying to do. itext7 and the free online book looks like a great place to start for me.

Comment: The web is full of bad sample code. Always go to the official web site first.